# WP7.5 and jquerymobile input placeholders

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

So i am creating a mobile version of my employers website using jquery mobile. So far, very good and everything works as expected.
But there are some areas where users would input some data, to submit a form. For ease of use on such small screens every input utilizes "placeholders" that was introduced with html5.

Works like a charm on anything but WP7.5. So without appropiate labels it does not make sense where to type what (note, in accordance to jquery's recommendations, i have made hidden labels associated to their respective input fields).

So i searched around for various javascripts that can work around this issue, but none of them works on windows phones for some reason.

Anyone have a suggestions? Ideas? Workarounds? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny, after having trying to find a solution for hours on end, after writing i found a solution.
I took out the code for adding placeholders from Zurb's excellent Foundation framework. For anyone stopping by with the same problem, look here: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because both Desktop and Windows Phone versions of IE9 [**don't support the input placeholder attribute**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder).

What you can do is use a [**Polyfill**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill), like this one: https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill